# Sublime Text 2 - plugin to show objects and variables?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there any plugin or way for Sublime Text 2 to show you your objects, functions, and variables on the side?

I am working with PHP and Javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you don`t need a Plugin to do this.

Just press Control + R (on Win) to get a List of all available functions, objects and variables.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

For the MAC users the command is `CMD + R`

This will open a popup with all the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to vote here in order to see this functionality implemented in SublimeText : http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/19343-a-class-browser-integrated-with-minimap/

In the meantime, `CTRL+R` is the only alternative...

Comment: The user is asking to see functions list on the side, NOT in the mini map! The correct feature to vote is this one: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/50879-add-a-function-list-side-bar/